# Javascript Date compare

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, if I have dates in the following string formats (mm/dd/yyyy)

```
date1 = "11/16/2015"
date2 = "11/09/2015"
date3 = "10/31/2015"
```

Can I directly run comparisions on them ?

like

```
date1 < date2
date2 > date3
```

is this the correct way to compare them ? Will it automatically consider the dates (like 31st Oct < 3rd Nov)

Answer (score 2):

You cant do this with string format you have to convert your dates to `Date()` object before comparaison :

```
var date1_parts= date1.split("/");
date1 = new Date(date1_parts[2], date1_parts[0] - 1, date1_parts[1]);

var date2_parts= date2.split("/");
date2 = new Date(date2_parts[2], date2_parts[0] - 1, date2_parts[1]);
```

Now you can compare them using `<` or `>` signs :

```
date1 > date2
true
date1 < date2
false
date1 == date2
false
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx..so one of my dates is the current date & other I get from screen in string format ("mm/dd/yyyy") ...So how do I compare these 2, since 1st one is going to be new Date() and 2nd is going to be string from screen ?

Comment: You're welcome bro, the same think you can use `>`  or `<` since the _string from screen_ are also be `new Date()` after conversion, so the both will have the same type `Date`.

Comment: And for difference between the 2 dates, can I directly do subtract "-"

Comment: Yes you can, that will give you difference between two dates in `millisecondes`.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert to the date type then compare them

```
var d1 = new Date("11/16/2015");
var d2 = new Date("11/09/2015");

d1>d2  //true
d2>d1  //false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date into `time` format and then compare it.

```js
date1 = new Date("11/16/2015").getTime();
date2 = new Date("11/09/2015").getTime();
date3 = new Date("10/31/2015").getTime();

// and then
// date1 < date2;
// date2 > date3;

// example
alert(date1 > date2);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime